# SQS - How far out of order might messages be delivered?

Tags: amazon-sqs

I have a use case for SQS where I'll be sending messages about specific objects within a system. Each object will have a message at most every 20 seconds, and there are hundreds of thousands (potentially millions) of objects, which means I'll be handling tens of thousands (potentially hundreds of thousands) of messages per second. The volume of messages precludes using FIFO queues.

Most of the time, I don't care about in-order messaging. If messages for two different objects get delivered in a different order than they were emitted, that's fine. What could potentially be a problem is if two messages relating to the same object were delivered out of order.

Given that each object would only have events every 20 seconds, and [20 seconds is an eternity in computing time](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-infinite-space-between-words/), it strikes me that it would be very unlikely for two messages sent 20 seconds apart (with potentially millions of messages between them) to be delivered  out of order. That said, I haven't been able to find any hard data about out-of-order delivery with SQS. I know it's a thing that can happen, but I haven't seen any measured data about it.

I'm wondering if there is any kind of measured data on the probability that a message gets delivered X amount of time out of order, or X messages out of order.

Comment: No data to show, but anyone with a cursory familiarity with SQS architecture will tell you it is possible - even on the magnitude of minutes or hours (much more rare, but still possible). The main promise is "at least once delivery, roughly in order".

Answer (score 0):

SQS makes no guarantee about how far out of order a message can appear for a non-FIFO queue.

The most-related measurement I've seen to what your looking for is [this experiment](https://softwaremill.com/amazon-sqs-performance-latency/) that found processing times for a message to be available for polling after it has been submitted to the queue. They also have a link to source code if you want to replicate the experiment to gather your own metrics.

If you absolutely must have them in the original order, you have a few options. They're not necessarily good options, but they are options.

1. Determine a way to horizontally partition your object IDs into *n* buckets, and use *n* different FIFO queues. (Probably the best option.)
2. Add your own sequence numbers to the messages.
3. Partition your messages into queues based on the current time. Drain each queue in order. (For example, you might publish to a single queue for only 4 seconds, and rotate sequentially through a group of 15 queues.)
4. Use a database and store the message timestamps in way that allows you to get the oldest message.